# Create Dataframe Columns Automatically with Different Names

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dynamic-columns

How can I create dataframe columns automatically with different names

I have this code

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['A']*5)
df.loc[len(df)]=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Which gives the result

```
   A  A  A  A  A
0  1  2  3  4  5
```

And I want the column names to be

```
   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
0  1   2   3   4   5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible pass to `DataFrame` correct columns names:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=[f'A{i}' for i in range(1, 6)])
df.loc[len(df)]=[1,2,3,4,5]
print (df)
  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
0  1  2  3  4  5
```

If need change values later with enumerate all columns names use:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['A']*5)

s = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns += s.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df.loc[len(df)]=[1,2,3,4,5]

print (df)
  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
0  1  2  3  4  5
```

---

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['A']*2 + ['B'] * 2 + ['C'])

s = df.columns.to_series()

df.columns += s.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

df.loc[len(df)]=[1,2,3,4,5]

print (df)
  A1 A2 B1 B2 C1
0  1  2  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 2):

To handle an arbitrary input list use `enumerate`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=[f'{a}{b}' for b,a in enumerate(['A']*5, start=1)])
df.loc[len(df)]=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

To handle any type of object without creating a copy, use `itertools.repeat`:

```
from itertools import repeat
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=[f'{a}{b+1}' for a,b in zip(repeat('A'), range(5))])
df.loc[len(df)]=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

output:

```
   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
0   1   2   3   4   5
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is with `enumerate`, if you are doing this after creating the DataFrame (doing this when creating the DataFrame, as suggested by @jezrael, IMO is a better option):

```py
df.columns = [f"{col}{num+1}" for num, col in enumerate(df.columns)]
df

   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
0   1   2   3   4   5
```

Comment: Oops I just had added this alternative :p

Comment: all good; the more the merrier :)